# What is the C# equivalent of Apache POI api?

Tags: apache-poi

I have a need to replicate a framework I built ij Java using the Apache POI api to read data from MS Excel. I have no idea what to use that is an equivalent of apache POI library. Any ideas please anyone?

Comment: EPPlus, easier than Open XML SDK

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you want to do.

One option is [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi), which is a .Net port of Apache POI to .Net

Another option is to use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), and then Apache POI itself directly from within .Net.

Comment: Thanks for your response. "Apache POI itself from within .Net" i thought its for java only?

Comment: Yes, it is - that's why you need IKVM to translate

Comment: Has anyone tried "Syncfusion Essential XlsIO". It seems to have a good rating. https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel. https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/Syncfusion.XlsIO.Net.Core. Better than NPOI, ratings can always be misleading.

Comment: The current location of NPOI is https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi

Comment: github.com/tonyqus/npoi is closed source by the author(after maintaining it for 10+ years)

Comment: NPOI remains active as of late 2023.  Look here: https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi.  Also consider OpenXML, the Microsoft-sanctioned SDK for Excel, MS Word and PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) for manipulating MS Office document formats since Office 2007.