# ExcelDataReader AsDataSet method crashes with OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

What's the best library to read Excel files, I used `ExcelDataReader` and it seems dealing only small sizes < 1mo.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300915/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-apache-poi-api

Comment: Do you have a sample Excel file that I can use to reproduce this issue? It's been reported before, https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/193, but so far we haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: [Link to Excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S_7Q5MC30IgT8ziVMfUJvQrtyrTvmPx5fhDoKWcgaNk/edit?usp=drive_web)

Comment: Why do you want to read an Excel file? You can connect it like a database with a connection string by using oledb or ... ;).

Comment: @shA.t thanks for your reply, i've compared some excel files to each others with using some libraries in order to facilitate my task.

Comment: Consider reading huge data from Excel by using Excel-Helpers will not give you a good performance; instead will give you some features like in Excel, If you want to to read data and compare them or any other data analyzing, use Excel data like a Database ;).